# GHCi loading distant files/file traversing

Tags: haskell, filepath, ghci

I'm super new with Haskell and GHCi. Fair warning. I'm trying to load a .hs file with the :load command, but the file is saved far from where my GHCi bin folder is, ie

> C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\bin

I want to get to this directory so that I can use

> :load hw2.hs

to load my module. But I'm struggling to get there.
I've tried

> :cd 'C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\bin'

with errors returned.
What's the proper syntax for changing to this directory? What about if there are spaces in the file path? (C:\Users\Kyle\My Documents\bin)

Also what command can I enter to see my current directory?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you can't use quotes with `:cd` – you just want

```
Prelude> :cd C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\bin
```

or, if you start in `C:\Users\Kyle`, then just

```
Prelude> :cd Documents\bin
```

This is also true for handling paths with spaces;

```
Prelude> :cd My Documents
```

will place you into the `My Documents` subdirectory of the current directory.

Comment: I found this when I was trying to cd to a directory named "Google Drive".  I had tried ':cd Google\ Drive', ':cd "Google Drive"', etc.  It never occurred to me to just try ':cd Google Drive'. :-)

Comment: FYI, I verified that single backslashes work, as in your examples.

Comment: @espertus: Ah good, then a year later I can update this to be certain :-)

Comment: The annoying thing is that ghci tab completes file names in this context, but adds slashes when it completes one with a space in the name...

Answer (score 0):

'C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\bin' I think it should be

```
'C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\bin'
```

or just use forward slashes / instead. It will work for paths with spaces too.